# Disabling the user to change the source of the HTML page

Tags: php, html

in my homepage, i display the pictures of the members. And, all of these pictures have a href tag which directs the page to their profile page. This page, profile.php, gets the relevant information from the a href, like

```
 <a href= "profile.php?name=james stone">
```

However, this url shows up in the url so that if the user change the url's "name" part as, say "abc", the site tries to get a person whose name is abc. In conclusion, The site tries to display non-existent person "abc" which results in lots of errors. How can i disable users to change the url?

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, you cannot control what the user can change in the HTML source.

Your approach for managing non existent URLs is wrong.

Instead, you should make an error page, if the user does not exist and display "User does not exist".

Answer (score 4):

You can't. Catch the error and display an error page to the user »The requested user does not exist.«. Always code defensively.

Answer (score 2):

You still have to handle the error if user doesn't exist. Because users can always change the username from url (which is a more common case), even if they didn't change it from html source.

Sometimes users can be deleted, but people will have the urls to their profile page remembered in their browser history, or stored somewhere as a shortcut. So in anyway, there will be alot of cases where user goes to the non existent user profile, and despite the number of the errors that occur, you need to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

well you can attach some encoded format of name with that
so if some one tries to change the name he would never find the encoded key with it
n you just need to check the key for your page no extra work required from database
eg.  "profile.php?name=james&key=asdkasndka" 
key could be md5 or some substring of md5 of the "name"

Comment: Sounds like security through obscurity to me …

Comment: Still the problem persists, that the user can manipulate the URL. The question is how to prevent this manipulation.